# Debug TV resolution switch

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios-simulator, sigterm

I want to write an iPad application that uses extern TV.
To detect external displays, I use the recommended code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
  {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // ...

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(screenDidChange:) name:UIScreenDidConnectNotification        object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(screenDidChange:) name:UIScreenDidDisconnectNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(screenDidChange:) name:UIScreenModeDidChangeNotification object:nil];
    //...
  }

// ...

- (void)screenDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
  {
    // ...
  }
```

However, if I run this in the simulator and switch TV's resolution (or switch "TV out" on or off) I do *not* get the notification but the application terminates by `sigterm`.

Is there any way to test this in the simulator?

Comment: Can somebody please explain the downvote (especially without comment).

Comment: Upvoted; I get the same problem. It's not related to your code snippet though.